# Get NameError when printing out the result, but I've assigned a variable to it

Tags: python

```py
seq = 'TGCCTTGGGCACCATGCAGTACCAAACGGAACGATAGTG'

for nucleotide in seq:
    if nucleotide == 'A':
        a_nt = seq.count('A')
    elif nucleotide == 'G':
        g_nt = seq.count('G')
    elif nucleotide == 'C':
        c_nt = seq.count('C')
    elif nucleotide == 'T':
        t_nt = seq.count('T')
    elif nucleotide == 'N':
        n_nt = seq.count('N')
    else:
        sys.exit("Did not code")

    print(a_nt, g_nt, c_nt, t_nt, n_nt)
```

Error:

```py
NameError: name 'n_nt' is not defined. Did you mean: 'a_nt'?
```

If the nucleotide is not in 'AGCTN', `sys.exit("no this code")`.
Even counts of N is zero, it should be printed out.

If I print out a, g, c, and t, it works well. But `n_nt` is not working.

Comment: There is no `N` in your `seq`, hence the `elif nucleotide == 'N':` is never true, and hence `n_nt` does not get set. You can avoid the error by initializing if before the loop: `n_nt = 0` (or whatever makes sense as a default value).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How to print 'N' out even if it's not in the sequence. I expect it will be zero.

Comment: Initialize `n_nt = 0` before the loop. To be on the safe side, do that for `a_nt` and the others as well, so that your code doesn't break when the other letters are not in `seq`.

Comment: Alternately, start with a dictionary with all your letters as keys and values set to 0 then update them in the loop, or use a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object to do the counting and output a dictionary for you

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys! Thanks for sharing about other alternative ways to make my mind more clearly. I made it! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just count everything without the `for` loop, then all variables are set, even if zero:

```py
seq = 'TGCCTTGGGCACCATGCAGTACCAAACGGAACGATAGTG'

a_nt = seq.count('A')
g_nt = seq.count('G')
c_nt = seq.count('C')
t_nt = seq.count('T')
n_nt = seq.count('N')

print(a_nt, g_nt, c_nt, t_nt, n_nt)

# or more efficient
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(seq)
for letter in 'AGCTN':
    print(counts[letter], end=' ')
```

Output:

```
11 11 10 7 0
11 11 10 7 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `collections.Counter`

```py
from collections import Counter

possible_nucleotides = ["A", "G", "C", "N", "T"]
seq = "TGCCTTGGGCACCATGCAGTACCAAACGGAACGATAGTG"

seq_counts = Counter(seq)

missing_nucleotides = {x: 0 for x in set(possible_nucleotides) - set(seq_counts.keys())}

seq_counts.update(missing_nucleotides)
```

then `seq_counts` will look like this:

```
Counter({'G': 11, 'A': 11, 'C': 10, 'T': 7, 'N': 0})
```

Keep in mind that updating `Counter` is purely optional as trying to access specific key will return `0` if not present